# count(*) using left join taking long time to respond

Tags: mysql, performance

I have a MySQL query for showing the count of data in the Application listing page.

query

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM cnitranr left join cnitrand on cnitrand.tx_no=cnitranr.tx_no
```

Explain screen shot
[image]

Indexes on cnitranr

```
tx_no (primary )approx 1 crore of data[ENGINE MYISAM]
```

index on cnitrand

```
(tx_no secondary)approx 2 crore of data[ENGINE MYISAM]
```

Profiler output is like this 
[image: profiler]

[image: Total count after execution is]

Can anyone suggest possibilities in optimizing this query or may i want to run a crone job for counting the count .Please help.

Comment: `SELECT COUNT(null) FROM cnitranr left join cnitrand on cnitrand.tx_no=cnitranr.tx_no` will slightly improve performance. Also enable mysql cache. Also it's a good idea to cut this kind of big data in chunks. I don't expect any user to read `31770999` rows. So you can have multiple tables (or even databases) and get data from the respective datasource according request.

Comment: Left join returns all values for left-side table independently on-join condition. Do you really want to get count of all items for `cnitranr`? Maybe you should use INNER JOIN?

Comment: @PSR I have tried that but that also taking long time . i think i have to do some trick in pagination .

Comment: It doesn't really go faster than this I'm afraid ... a join of 31 million records takes time.

Comment: @Jack me too realize that now .want to partition

Comment: If you can't make any progress, try asking at http://explainextended.com/, the guy can very probably help you.

Comment: @Atber that will strip data from left table if join condition fails, i don't want that .

Comment: @Tomalak I HAVE pasted the link there ,thanks

Comment: @ArunKillu: this cannot be made efficient, not with 20M+ records. What are you trying to achieve with this query?

Comment: @Quassnoi actually client want to paginate the transactions so total number of result is required .can you suggest some other methods

Comment: @ArunKillu: do they need exact number that much? Google and Facebook and any other app with decent data volumes don't show exact numbers, and that's for a reason: it's very hard to obtain them. You see things like "approx. 16000 results" on Google, or "downloaded 10M+ times" on Google Play etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to implement a materialized view.

Since MySQL does not support them directly, you would need to create a table like that:

```
CREATE TABLE totals (cnt INT)
```

and write a trigger on both tables that would increment and decrement `cnt` on `INSERT`, `UPDATE` and `DELETE` to each of the tables.

Note that if you have a record with many linked records in either table, the `DML` affecting such a record would be slow.

On large data volumes, you very rarely need exact counts, especially for pagination. As I said in a comment above, Google, Facebook etc. only show approximate numbers on paginated results.

It's very unlikely that a person would want to browse through 20M+ records on page only able to show 100 or so.